# Carrier apps still appear after stock android installation

Tags: device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-s-6

So I have been trying to install stock android on my phone, but not having the desired result. Before I try on my current phone (Galaxy S9), I've been practicing on an old S6 edge.  The phone was bought in Canada, and has the Telus build on it from the factory.

- Downloaded Odin (version 3.13)
- Downloaded the firmware from Sam mobile (specifically, I have picked the XAC, carrier agnostic product code)
- Flash with Odin
- Reboot and wipe cache partition
- Factory reset

But when I restart the phone - BAM! Telus bloatware remains installed.

Any idea what I am doing wrong, and how to do it correctly?

Edit: clarified question

Answer (score 1):

Samsung have its own partition `/preload` for its bloatware which is usually not wiped on factory reset

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove them, get root access on the phone and install Titanium Backup form the Google play store. Make sure you have unknown sources turned on. Open Titanium Backup, wait for it to set up, then select Backup/Restore at the top. Find the app you want to remove, and select it. On the menu that appears, tap Backup at the top of the menu, so if anything goes wrong you can try to restore it. Then press "Un-install !". After it's done, reboot your phone. If all goes well, you can go back to the list of apps, find the backup you made, and delete it.

!!WARNING!! IF YOU DELETE AN APP REQUIRED BY THE SYSTEM, YOU COULD SCREW UP YOUR ROM AND HAVE TO REFLASH IT! YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED!!

Edit: this probably isn't a good idea

Comment: rooting is not a good idea especially with samsungs vaultkeeper these days